# Como puedo hacer para que el programa regrese al menu?

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<math.h>


void problema1(void);
void problema2(void);
void problema3(void);
void problema4(void);
void problema5(void);
void problema6(void);
void problema7(void);
void problema8(void);
void problema9(void);
void problema10(void);
int main(){

    int  opc=0;


    printf("================================\n");
    printf("selecione una opcion\n");
    printf("================================\n");
    printf("1).operacion y+b/a-b\n");
    printf("2).area y perimetro de un rectangulo\n");
    printf("3).calificiones aprovado/reprovado\n");
    printf("4).calculo de salario de trabajador\n");
    printf("5).operacion funcion 100\n");
    printf("6).calculo del factorial\n");
    printf("7).tabla de temperaturas\n");
    printf("8).calculo de potencia\n");
    printf("9).notas de un estudidiante\n");
    printf("10).cuadrados y cubos\n");
    printf("=================================\n");
    scanf("%d",&opc);
    printf("=================================\n");

    switch(opc)
    {

    case 1: 
    problema1();
    break;  

    case 2:
    problema2();
    break;

    case 3:
    problema3();
    break;

    case 4:
    problema4();
    break;

    case 5:
    problema5();
    break;

    case 6:
    problema6();
    break;

    case 7:
    problema7();
    break;

    case 8:
    problema8();
    break;

    case 9:
    problema9();
    break;

    case 10:
    problema10();
    break;

    }

    }

void problema1(){

        float y,b,a,r;

    bool system ;
    printf("dados 3 numeros enteros, realice la siguiente operación: y+b/a-b\n \n");

printf("introdusca el valor de  y\n ");
scanf("%f",&y);
printf("introdusca el valor de  b\n ");
scanf("%f",&b);
printf("introdusca el valor de  a\n ");
scanf("%f",&a);
r=(y+b)/(a-b);

printf("la respuesta de la operacion es %.2f\n",r);
getchar();
}

void problema2()
{
    int x,y,p,a;
    printf("dados como datos la base y la altura de un rectangulo, calcule e imprima el perimetro y el area. El a = base*altura y p = 2(base+altura).  Despliegue el area y el perimetro\n \n");
    printf("introduzca la medida de la altura del rectangulo\n");
    scanf("%d",&x);
    printf("introduzca la medida de la base del rectangulo\n");
    scanf("%d",&y);
    a=(y*x);
    p=2*(x+y);

    printf("la altura del rectangulo es %d\n",a);
    printf("el perimetro del rectangulo es %d\n",p);
    getchar();
}

void problema3(){
    int score1,score2,score3,score4,score5;
    printf("introduzca la calificacion 1\n");
    scanf("%d",&score1);
    if(score1>=71){
        printf("aprovado\n");
    }
    else{
        printf("reprovado\n");
    }
        printf("introduzca la calificacion 2\n");
    scanf("%d",&score2);
    if(score2>=71){
        printf("aprovado\n");
    }
    else{
        printf("reprovado\n");
    }
            printf("introduzca la calificacion 3\n");
    scanf("%d",&score3);
    if(score3>=71){
        printf("aprovado\n");
    }
    else{
        printf("reprovado\n");
    }
            printf("introduzca la calificacion 4\n");
    scanf("%d",&score4);
    if(score4>=71){
        printf("aprovado\n");
    }
    else{
        printf("reprovado\n");
    }
            printf("introduzca la calificacion 5\n");
    scanf("%d",&score5);
    if(score5>=71){
        printf("aprovado\n");
    }
    else{
        printf("reprovado\n");
    }
    getchar();
}
void problema4(){
        float ht,sh,d,sueldo,total,sueldoneto;
    printf("introduzca las horas trabajadas \n");
    scanf("%f",&ht);
    printf("introduzca el salario por hora\n");
    scanf("%f",&sh);
    printf("introduzaca la deducciones a realizarse\n");
    scanf("%f",&d);
    sueldo=ht+sh*30-d;
    sueldoneto=ht+sh*30;
    if(sueldo<=1000){
        total=sueldo*0.25;
    }
    else{
        total=sueldo*1;
    }
    if(sueldo>1000&sueldo<=1500){
        total=sueldo*0.21;
    }
    else{
        total=sueldo*1;
        }
        if(sueldo>1500){
            total=sueldo*0.18;
        }
    printf("el sueldo neto es %.2f\n",sueldoneto);
    printf("el saladio es %.2f\n",total);
    getchar();
}

void problema5(){
        int num, v;
    float r;
    printf("digite el numero 1 para multiplicar\n");
    printf("digite el numero 2 para sumar\n");
    printf("digite el numero 3 para dividir\n");
    scanf("%d",&num);
    printf("ingrese un valor para realizar a operacion\n");
    scanf("%d",&v);
    if(num=1){
        r=100*v;
    }else if(num=2){
        r=100+v;}
    else if(num=3){
        r=100/v;
    }
    printf("el resultado de la operacion es %.2f\n",r);
    getchar();
}
void problema6(){
        int fac=1,n,r;
    printf("introduzca el numero para calcular el factorial\n");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    for(r=1;r<=n;r++){
        fac=fac*r;
    }
    printf("\nel factorial del numero %d  es %d",n,fac);
    getchar();

}
void problema7(){
    float f,c;
    for(f=1;f <= 200; f++){
    c=(f -32) * 5/9;
    printf("\n fahrenheit %.1f | celcius %.1f",f,c);
    }
    getch();

}
void problema8(){
    int exp;
        float base, result;

        printf("introduzca un numero:\n");
        scanf("%f",&base);
        printf("la potencia de %.2f es: \n",base);
        for(int x=1;x<=9;x++){
            result=pow(base,x);
            if(result<=2000){
                printf("| %.2f",result);
            }
        else{
            x=9;
        }   
        }

}
void problema9(){
int i,e;
    float p,total;
    printf("ingrese el numero de articulos que va a comprar\n");
    scanf("%d",&e);
    printf("introduzca el precio del articulo\n");
    scanf("%f",&p);
        total=p*e;
        total+=total*0.07;
        if(total>500){
            total-=total*0.10;
        }
    printf("el total de la compra es |%.2f|\n",total);
    getchar();

}
void problema10(){
    int dig,c,c2;
 printf("\n ===================================");
 printf("\n numeros 1 al 25 cubos y cuadrados ");
 printf("\n ===================================");
 for(dig=0;dig <= 25; dig++) {
       c=pow(dig,2);
       c2=pow(dig,3);
    printf ("\n %d|   %d   | %d", dig, c, c2);
    }
}
```

Comment: seguro que el código es c#?

Comment: si, porque?  estoy usando devc++ como compilador, pero la sintaxis es del lenguaje C#

Comment: c# no usa includes

Comment: @shadow efectivamente, no es C#

Comment: sabia que no era C#, alguien debería hacer la corrección en la etiqueta principalmente quien preguntó

Comment: Es imposible que devc++ te compile código C#.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

haces esto:

int main(){

```
char respuesta; (nueva variable para guardar respuesta)
int opc = 0; 

do{

printf("----------- bla bla bla


problema 1 etc...
...

problema10(...){
...
}

printf("Desea realizar otra operacion(s/n)?\n");
fflush(stdin);
scanf("%c",&respuesta);

}while(respuesta=='s');

system("pause");
```

}

---

de esa manera va a preguntar si el usuario quiere seguir haciendo operaciones, si elige 's' va a seguir mostrando el menu, si elige 'n' sale. Ojo , siempre va a entrar al menu aunque sea 1 sola vez, si queres que pregunte la primera vez vas a tener que agregar la pregunta arriba de todo y abajo hacer un while.
Para el system("pause") necesitas importar la biblioteca stdlib.h
y eso es lenguaje C.

Comment: Todo cool, pero me sale el [Error] 'respuesta' was not declared in this scope

Comment: declara la variable char respuesta; y fijate de que este escrita igual que en el while

Comment: ahi lo cambie perdon, la declaracion de variables va antes del do{

Comment: Ahora si funciono, MUCHAS GRACIAS! de verdad.

Comment: @DavidRicardolee Si la respuesta te sirvió, por favor, *acéptala*; no tienes mas que *hacer click* en el icono del *check* `✓` a la izquierda :-)